# QMYSQL driver not loaded even though it is there

Tags: mysql, qt, driver

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

this is the error I get when I run my application. I am on OS X. Installing SQL drivers appears to be a painful task and a poorly documented one. From the QT site:

```
cd $QTDIR/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql
qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/local/include" "LIBS+=-L/usr/local/lib -lmysqlclient_r" mysql.pro
make
```

$QTDIR is not only not defined, but this directory doesn't even exist. This is the closest I could find:

```
/Users/me/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/plugins/sqldrivers/
```

And it is filled with dylibs for all the installed drivers...

Comment: $QTDIR means the location of the Qt sources here, i.e. an extracted Qt source tarball. As the driver is there, it probably cannot be loaded because the mysqlclient library cannot be found at runtime.

Comment: Do you know how this can be corrected?

Comment: Do you have the library on your system? If yes, try with setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH. Check the plugin dependencies with `otool -L`.

Comment: Do you found a solution for this ?